# NodeWebkit "always on top" on top of fullscreen applications?

Tags: windows, opengl, directx, overlay, node-webkit

I've been playing around with a NodeWebkit application I'm building and I'd like to know if there's any way of making the app run on top of everything.

I know you can set always on top to true within the `package.json` file (or call the method on the window object) but the application doesn't go above fullscreen applications such as games.

Since what I'm building is supposed to be a game overlay (think: Steam overlay, UPlay overlay) I desperately need this functionality, is it possible? Is it possible with NodeWebkit?

Comment: Tons of downvotes but no reason explaining why? Helpful.

Comment: It pretty much has nothing to do with node webkit, node or javascript that's probably the reason for the downvotes. checkout my answer it might point you in the right direction

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to overlay graphics on Windows games?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3266346/how-to-overlay-graphics-on-windows-games)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible, but not as easy as you may think.
If you want to overlay games the problem is that the game engine "takes control" over the graphics card and renders ONLY the game.
that means that your application in the background is not rendered at all.

that means you need to "inject" yourself into that process.
you do this by talking to the OpenGL or DirectX directly

you can find more information on it
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/925981/overlaying-on-a-3d-fullscreen-application), [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3266346/how-to-overlay-graphics-on-windows-games), [And Here](http://overlay-api.net/)

Comment: Hey, thanks for getting back to me. My research led me along similar lines but you've definitely been the best to explain it thus far. It will likely be something I wont even bother trying to do as it'll take a lot longer than the time I originally scope out of my project but it's definitely great to know. Thanks a lot!